# Is any way to connect mtproto client ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, proxy

I was install `mtproto` on my server.

but any way or solution to set **mtproto** on ubuntu client system wide?

because I can see `HTTP` , `HTTPS`, `socks` protocol on proxy option but any `mtporto`.

thanks for advice.

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: how Can I connect to this protocol? any package any  way ?

Comment: Please describe what you have tried, what you expected to happen, and what the result was.

Comment: @SorenA I haven't any Idea to connect to `mtporto`!!

Answer (score 0):

At this moment `mtproto` is only available for `telegram` Cloud chats (server-client encryption), please check following link and read about it.
[Mtproto - General Description](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto#general-description)